# sql query - joining two results after comparison

Tags: mysql, sql, magento

I need to get a list of the products and price from my magento site using SQL. I have two queries. The first allows me to select the entity_id and value from a table, The value is the price.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `entity_id` , `value` FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal`
```

Then I have another query which selects the name using the entity id.

```
SELECT var.value AS product_name, e.entity_id
FROM catalog_product_entity e,
     eav_attribute eav,
     catalog_product_entity_varchar var
WHERE e.entity_type_id = eav.entity_type_id 
  AND eav.attribute_code = 'name' 
  AND eav.attribute_id = var.attribute_id
  AND var.entity_id = e.entity_id
```

http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/tutorials/eav-database-structure/

I am having major trouble combining these two sql queries. So i am trying to find the method on how to can select the product name and put it against the price depending on its entity id matching.

So basically comparing one column against another and Joining them accordingly.

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper CREATE and INSERT statements (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: I am using Magento so i amnot entirly sure what tables I have to create. @Strawberry i will update my box with more information tho

Answer (score 0):

Something like this... but without proper DDLs it's hard to say for sure...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.entity_id
              , x.value
              , var.value product_name
           FROM catalog_product_entity_decimal x
           JOIN catalog_product_entity e
             ON e.entity_id = x.entity_id
           JOIN eav_attribute eav
             ON eav.entity_type_id = e.entity_type_id 
           JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar var
             ON var.attribute_id = eav.attribute_id 
          WHERE eav.attribute_code = 'name'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT `entity_id` , `value` FROM   `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table1
INNER JOIN (SELECT var.value AS product_name, e.entity_id
FROM catalog_product_entity e,
     eav_attribute eav,
     catalog_product_entity_varchar var
WHERE e.entity_type_id = eav.entity_type_id 
  AND eav.attribute_code = 'name' 
  AND eav.attribute_id = var.attribute_id
  AND var.entity_id = e.entity_id) table2

  ON table1.entity_id = table2.entity_id
```